# Color email address in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2016 question on sending emails:  I have both IN company email contacts;  and out of my company contacts.  When I send an email to Dave Smith internal person  but then I have Dar Smith an external person.  Can I color code an email address to make sure I dont accidently send an email (especially with confidential info) to wrong person?   I m looking for a back up stop gap and maybe if I could color all my outside email blue it will help me.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you mean color the email address in the To, Cc, Bcc field when composing a new email, I don't think Outlook provides such an option. However, Outlook does show a notification in the infobar when you are sending to an external recipient.

[image]